# Ocaml Type-inference of fun f [x; y; z] -> (f x y), (f z);;

Tags: ocaml, type-inference

I have this OCaml function:

```
fun f [x; y; z] -> (f x y), (f z);;
```

and the teacher wants me to answer: what is the type of this function.
But i do not understand what does `[x; y; z]` means? Is it a list ? i don't think so because the solution is

```
('a -> 'a-> 'b) -> 'a list -> b*('a->'b))
```

and it means that `z` is of different type and I cannot undestand how do I get it. Is it a vector? a sequence of three inputs? don't think so neither because otherwise it would be

```
fun f x y z -> (f x y), (f z);;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: It's a list, therefore x, y and z must have the same type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, let's evaluate type of `fun f [x; y; z] -> (f x y), (f z)` this.

- Our function takes to arguments and returns a tuple. So it's type will be `_ -> _ -> _ * _` where underscores are not evaluated yet parts. We will evaluate them below
- Our 2nd argument is a list , so types of `x` , `y` and `z` are the same.
  `_ -> 'a list -> _ * _`
- when we look at 1st expression in result tuple (`f x y`) we see that `f` is applied to `x` and `y`, so we can rewrite result as: 
  `('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b * _`
- in second expression in function result expression we see `f z`. But we already know that `f` is `'a -> 'a -> 'b` already, so it seems that `f z` has type `'a -> 'b`.
  `('a -> 'a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b * ('a -> 'b)`
- Et voilà!

Comment: Thank you. I have 2 more questions: 1: in step 3 did you mean "we see that f is applied to x and y" instead of "we see that f is applied to x and z"? 2: f z has type 'a->'b because it still miss an arguments and i know it mess an argument because of f x y (where i see f needs 2 parameters: x and y)?

Comment: 2nd: I think you get it right. It's hard to formulate it right because these functions are in curried form and technically all functions there have only 1 argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list for sure. It cannot be anything else.

Your function accepts two arguments. The first one is a function, and the second is a list, that is deconstructed into three values. The function accepts two arguments. Since all functions in OCaml is currified it can also accept one argument and "return" a function that will accept the other argument and yield a result.

So, at the end you have a pair of a result of an application of function `f` to the first two elements of a list, and a partial application of the same function to the third element of a list.

Hope, this answers your questions.